# Using Auth check with sanctum in laravel 8, does it work

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I have a couple of rules in my laravel SPA dashboard which dont seem to work, well they always return false and not sure it this is correct or that my logic is faulty.

I use Sanctum to provide a token for validation in Laravel 8 but I also have added in the begining of build a auth check in my blade parent view file.

My qeustion is does the laravel auth() work with sanctum and how can you see with PHP that sanctum  is valid/working

**vue.blade.php**

```
// this will not work when I login
@if (Auth::check())
    <script>
        window.Laravel = {!!json_encode(['isLoggedin' => true, 'user' => Auth::user()])!!}
    </script>
@else
    <script>
        window.Laravel = {!!json_encode(['isLoggedin' => false])!!}
    </script>
@endif
```

**loginController.php**

```
$credentials = [
    'email' => $request->email,
    'password' => $request->password,
];

if (auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
    if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
         $request->user()->createToken('token_name')->plainTextToken;
              return with logic
         }
    }
}
```

**config/auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    
    'auth' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `if (!Hash::check($request->password, $user->password))`
which means you are going to get `false` if password and hash matches. Remove `!` inside `if` statement

Also I don't understand why are you using `Hash::check()` when you are already authenticating user with `auth()->attempt()`

Comment: Sorry the ! shoudnt be there. I have copied this from a tutorial and had the feeling that this was redundant

Answer (score 0):

you have to try this

```
                $credentials = [
                            'email' => $request->email,
                            'password' => $request->password
                        ];
                      
                        
                        if (Auth::guard()->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
                            $token = auth()->user()->createToken('token_name')->accessToken;
                            return response()->json(['token' => $token,'Token Details' => auth()->user()], 200);
                        } else {
                            return response()->json(['error' => 'UnAuthorised'], 401);
                        }
```

Comment: When I login an refresh I see the message that it is not logged in auth::check() fails

Comment: Auth::guard('app')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])       you have add auth name   also here auth('app')->user();  like this then try this